# JavaScript not working inside AJAX loaded DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having a problem getting the javascript code to work inside an AJAX loaded div, I am trying to include jquery tabs but it not working, the ajax outputs text only and won't recognize the javascript. Any help would be nice.

Here is my js code:

```
var OpenedPage;

function load(url, target) {
    document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = 'Loading ...';
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (req != undefined) {
        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            loadDone(url, target);
        };
        req.open("GET", url, true);
        req.send("");
    }
}

function loadDone(url, target) {
    if (req.readyState == 4) { // only if req is "loaded"
        if (req.status == 200) { // only if "OK"
            document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = "loaded" + req.responseText;
        } else {
            document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = "Error:\n" + req.status + "\n" + req.statusText;
        }
    }
}

function unload() {
    if (OpenedPage == "divsignin") {
        unloaddivsignin();
    }
    if (OpenedPage == "divHowto") {
        unloaddivHowto();
    }

}

function ShowHidedivsignin() {
    unload();
    OpenedPage = "divsignin";
    load("../slogin.php", "divsignin");
    $("#divsignin").animate({"height": "toggle"}, {duration: 800});
}

function unloaddivsignin() {
    OpenedPage = "";
    $("#divsignin").animate({"height": "toggle"}, {duration: 800});
}

function ShowHidedivHowto() {
    unload();
    OpenedPage = "divHowto";
    load("../howto.php", "divHowto");
    $("#divHowto").animate({"height": "toggle"}, {duration: 800});
}

function unloaddivHowto() {
    OpenedPage = "";
    $("#divHowto").animate({"height": "toggle"}, {duration: 800});
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="divsignin" style="display:none;width:auto"> </div>


<a onClick="ShowHidedivHowto(); return false;" href="#">help</a>
```

Comment: Just for info, it's JavaScript, not java script :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't checked all your code but what are you using to trigger the javacript loaded into your div? the window/document ready functions will only fire once when the page is initially loaded...

Try the something like the following for the content loaded into the div...

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Two</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-3"><span>Three</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fragment-1">
        <p>First tab is active by default:</p>
        <pre><code>$('#example').tabs();</code></pre>
    </div>
    <div id="fragment-2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </div>
    <div id="fragment-3">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#tabs").tabs();
</script>
```

Note the script tag is at the end so it will be parsed after the tabs are loaded.

The alternative would be to modify the function called when AJAX is successful and add

```
 $("#tabs").tabs();
```

to the end of it - again this will make sure the code runs only after the contents have been loaded.

Comment: thanks Basiclife, i am not a js expert, so i paid a freelance programmer to build this code, and he dosent reply to my emails and left me stuck like this

Comment: Ok... Long story short there are 2 main things you're doing 1: defining functions to be run when triggered and 2: attaching those functions to triggers. The standard JQuery way to run code is when the document is ready - ie when the page is mostly loaded. This event is triggered only once and wouldn't fire again when you load the contents into the div. Can you show the JS you're loading into the div that isn't working and we can go from there...

Comment: okay, in the header of the main page i have attached jquery.js & jquery-tabs.js . and in the page that loads inside the div i have the html for the tabs. i tried also to include jquery.js & jquery-tabs.js inside the loaded page but still not working

Comment: Ok, going back to the 2 steps... You're defining what divs/elements should be tabs **BUT** you also need to run the code that actually turns them into tabs. That code should only run after the contents of the div have been loaded. Ignoring the bad AJAX usage (see Karim79's answer), you have to do one of 2 things: 1) in the function that is called when the AJAX works or 2) in javascript on the content that is loaded **but outside a function**, you should set up the tabs (as per http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs ) `$('#tabs').tabs()`

Comment: yes it works now, i added $("#tabs").tabs(); to the ajax code and it works 100% now. thank you all for the help

Comment: Not a problem at all - Welcome to SO, hopefully we'll see you around in the future.

Answer (score 7):

Since you are already using jQuery, you should start refactoring that to be more readable and therefore more maintainable. Notably, you can ditch that load function, and incorporate a pattern similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // <a class="help" href="help.html">help</a>
    $("a.help").live("click", function() {
        $("#divHowTo").html("Loading...");
        $.ajax({
            url: "../howto.php",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(html) {
                $("#divHowTo").html(html)
                    .animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 800 });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**I think you need this :**
**Try executing script with jquery rather than with innerHTML** :

**Instead of this :**

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML="<script>alert();</script>";
```

**Try this:**

```
$("#content").html("<script>alert();</script>");
```