# jquery autocompleter not working in ajax tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony1, jquery-autocomplete

I am using symfony framework. My program contains 3 tabs home,profile,interaction. For this i am using ajax tabs functionality. In interaction tab, i am using jquery autocomplete function for some text fileds. My default tab is interaction. At starting autocomplete working fine. But when i switch to other tab and came back to interaction tab, autocomplete function stopped working. Actually, I figured out that no javascript function is working in ajax tabs.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: see jquery is included in tabs. try an alert . post what error you getting

Comment: Hi...a small javascript function which contains alert also not working in ajax tabs. Thats the problem.

Comment: try to acces the page directly typing url ..not through ajax request. check view source

Comment: Its showing the following code at every autocomplete textbox:   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#autocomplete_homequestion_keyword5")
    .autocomplete('/frontend_dev.php/system/equivajax', jQuery.extend({}, {
      dataType: 'json',
      parse:    function(data) {
        var parsed = [];
        for (key in data) {
          parsed[parsed.length] = { data: [ data[key], key ], value: data[key], result: data[key] };
        }
        return parsed;
      }
    }, { }))
    .result(function(event, data) { jQuery("#homequestion_keyword5").val(data[1]); });
  });

Comment: Did you include the js library?

Comment: Hello....In other pages javascript is working fine (autocomplete also ). Only this Ajax tabs page giving problem. I am continuing existing project. It uses symfony framework. Do I have to explicitly include again ?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you have to manually include javascript code when symfony makes ajax calls. I haven't been able to find a workaround yet. That's why your code isn't working, because it doesn't see the jquery UI library.

PS, if you got this working, please share :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a symfony project too, and have the same problem, and searching a bit, i found this. Maybe can help you

[JavaScript not working inside AJAX loaded DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4476064/790535)

Says that when loading some data via ajax into the webpage, the triggers that makes the javascript (JQuery in your case) are defined to detect the 'ready' state of the document. And that happens only once, at the page loading. So when you load some content in your page, the document doesn't load again and the trigger does not react, so you javascript function is never executed.

I don't know how to fix it, i have to investigate more, but when i find out, i'll tell you.

Good luck