# JQuery ToolTip Not Working After AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm having a problem similar to this: [JavaScript not working inside AJAX loaded DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476064/javascript-not-working-inside-ajax-loaded-div) but my problem is that I don't have any event to bind to. I have this:

```
$('[title]').colorTip({color:'yellow'});
```

binding all elements with 'title' attribute to that object. It works fine on page reload. But on elements from AJAX call the story is different, it displays like the javascript doesn't exist. I know to bind elements to other events from AJAX using `live()`, but how do I bind elements that don't have 'events'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have to re-bind the tooltip after the ajax call.

```
$( document ).ajaxStop( function() {
    $('[title]').colorTip({color:'yellow'});
});
```

Or as suggested by jbabey, you might use the complete callback to re-bind the tooltip (simplified version from [here](http://www.bennadel.com/resources/presentations/jquery/demo21/index.htm)):

```
$(
function(){
    // Get a reference to the content div (into which we will load content).
    var jContent = $( "#content" );             
    // Hook up link click events to load content.
    $( "a" ).click(
        function( objEvent ){
            var jLink = $( this );
            // Clear status list.
            $( "#ajax-status" ).empty();
            // Launch AJAX request.
            $.ajax(
                {
                    // The link we are accessing.
                    url: jLink.attr( "href" ),
                    // The type of request.
                    type: "get",
                    // The type of data that is getting returned.
                    dataType: "html",
                    complete: function(){
                        console.log("finalized ajax request");
                        //re-bind the tooltip
                        $('[title]').colorTip({color:'yellow'});
                    },
                    success: function( strData ){
                        console.log("ajax success");
                        console.log(strData);
                        // to something with the received data
                        jContent.html( strData );
                    }
                }                           
                );
            // Prevent default click.
            return( false );                    
        }
        );

}
);
```

Based upon your comment I included the following: You also have to make sure you bind the tooltip on page load:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $('[title]').colorTip({color:'yellow'});
});
```

Comment: it would probably be better to put this in the `complete` callback, unless he has multiple ajax calls manipulating the dom.

Comment: This fixes it for the ajax calls... but then, it's buggy as I have to make an Ajax call for it to work even on the elements that were there on first page load.

Comment: Not sure whether I understood you correctly, but you also have to make sure to bind your tooltip on page load. No need to make an ajax call for the first bind.. I adjusted my answer based upon your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a change event on the element.

```
$('title').live('change', function () {
whatever you want to do here
})
```

Then you would just trigger the change whenever you want the attribute to take effect.

```
$('title').trigger('change');
```

Comment: -1 .live() has been deprecated as of version 1.7.  .on is the replacement, and should be used going forward.